# Unbounded array of CGfloat

Tags: arrays, swift, cgfloat

I am trying to create an unbounded array in swift.  I have found examples of assigning unbounded arrays of Ints and basic Floats, but I am seeing issues when I try to cast the array as an array of CGFloats.  The snipet below has an array called vertices where I believe I have defined it as a unbounded array of CGFloats. As soon as I try to index the CGfloats, the compiler complains that Cannot subscript a value of type '[(GLfloat)]' with an index of type '((Int32))'  Perhaps I don't truly understand what the error is telling me. Can anyone explain the issue with subscripting an CGfloat array with a Int?

```
private func makeSomeCoords(cx: Float, cy: Float, cz: Float, r: Float, p:Int32)
{
    var theta1 = 0.0 as Float
    var theta2 = 0.0 as Float
    var theta3 = 0.0 as Float
    var ex = 0.0 as GLfloat
    var ey = 0.0 as GLfloat
    var ez = 0.0 as GLfloat
    var px = 0.0 as GLfloat
    var py = 0.0 as GLfloat
    var pz = 0.0 as GLfloat

    var vertices = [GLfloat]()  // <= My presumption is these are not declared correctly
    var normals = [GLfloat]()
    var texCoords = [GLfloat]()

    var abs_r = r as Float
    var abs_p = p as Int32

    if( abs_r < 0.0 ) {
        abs_r = -abs_r
    }

    if(abs_p < 0 ) {
        abs_p = -abs_p
    }

    for var i = 0 as Int32; i < p/2; ++i  {
        var i_fl = Float(i) as Float
        theta1 = i_fl * (Float(M_PI)*2.0) / Float(abs_p) - Float(M_PI_2)
        theta2 = (i_fl + 1.0) * (Float(M_PI)*2) / Float(abs_p) - Float(M_PI_2)

        for var j = 0 as Int32; j <= abs_p; ++j {
            theta3 = Float(j) * (Float(M_PI)*2) / Float(abs_p)

            ex = cosf(theta2) * cosf(theta3)
            ey = sinf(theta2)
            ez = cosf(theta2) * sinf(theta3)
            px = cx + abs_r * ex
            py = cy + abs_r * ey
            pz = cz + abs_r * ez

            vertices[((6*j)+(0%6))] = px  <= Complains Cannot subscript a value of type '[(GLfloat)]' with an index of type '((Int32))'
            vertices[((6*j)+(1%6))] = py
            vertices[((6*j)+(2%6))] = pz

            normals[(6*j)+(0%6)] = ex
            normals[(6*j)+(1%6)] = ey
            normals[(6*j)+(2%6)] = ez

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, you are talking about CGFloat and use GLFloat. The latter is definitly not always the same bit size :|

Comment: `Array.Index` is defined as an `Int` not `Int32`. You either need to change `abs_p` to be an `Int`, or 'cast' it before indexing the array.

Comment: Sorry, meant to up-vote David's answer.  I didn't realize the type checking was so extreme.  Changing the abs_p from Int32 to Int solved the issue.